# create dummy column in a query that its value come from a condition

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, crystal-reports, case, dummy-data

am preparing a query which i will use it in Crystal Report 
the query is working fine so far but I want to add one more column (dummy column) which will be filled based on a condition ,
this is the query :

```
select AcctCode
     , AcctName
     , Segment_0 + '-'+ Segment_1 as Acctnum
     , max(refdate) 
     , min(refdate)
     , sum(debit) as Debit
     , sum(credit)as Credit 
from oact t0 
  inner join jdt1 t1 on t0.acctcode = t1.Account
where (  Segment_0 LIKE '01%' 
      or segment_0 like '02%'  
      or Segment_0 like '03%'
      )  
      and 
      ( t0.Segment_1 = '01') 
      and  (refdate  between '2014-01-31' and '2015-12-27' )
group by AcctCode, AcctName,Segment_0, Segment_1
order by  AcctCode
```

---

if Segment_0 is start with '01' then the value in the dummy column will show 'A'
if Segment_0 is start with '02' then the value in the dummy column will show 'L'
if Segment_0 is start with '03' then the value in the dummy column will show 'E'
i tried to use if statement, and case  but luck wasn't in my side :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select AcctCode
     , AcctName
     , Segment_0 + '-'+ Segment_1 as Acctnum
     , max(refdate) 
     , min(refdate)
     , sum(debit) as Debit
     , sum(credit)as Credit 
     , case when Segment_0 LIKE '01%' then 'A'
            when segment_0 like '02%' then 'L' 
            when Segment_0 like '03%' then 'E'
            else 'X'   
       end dummy_column
from oact t0 
  inner join jdt1 t1 on t0.acctcode = t1.Account
where (  Segment_0 LIKE '01%' 
      or segment_0 like '02%'  
      or Segment_0 like '03%'
      )  
      and 
      ( t0.Segment_1 = '01') 
      and  (refdate  between '2014-01-31' and '2015-12-27' )
group by AcctCode, AcctName,Segment_0, Segment_1
order by  AcctCode
```